# How to toggle slidingSubmenus?

Tags: mmenu

I'd like to be able to toggle slidingSubmenus mode.  It looks like it's not possible to change the options dynamically:
var instance = api.getInstance();
instance.opts.slidingSubmenus = true;

It doesn't seem to work if I try reinitialising using the api, and it doesn't seem possible to destroy the menu and recreate.  But I know it's possible as the 'playground' on the mmenu website does it through an 'updateMenu()' function that I can't find.